# Fuzzy word searching using Chosen jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Chosen matches words from beginning by default and if we add the following option, it would match the words even from middle:

```
{search_contains: true}
```

But I would like to implement fuzzy matching using chosen in a similar manner which Sublime Text does. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/858 this feature still does not found the way into choosen's core. Try the fork including this feature: https://github.com/eliasdorneles/chosen - of course I did not test it and relay on their talk.